# "int" in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, operator-overloading

Can anyone tell me if, when compiling a c++ program, does g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5 change `int`s to `long int`s? if so, how can this be changed? If not, do I just overload `operator long`? Is it just like overloading operator uint32_t/uint64_t? It seems like a different type of typecasting (no pun intended).

[this](http://calccrypto.wikidot.com/programming%3auint128-t) is causing the errors:

```
uint128_t.h: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,
uint128_t)’:
uint128_t.h:593: error: conversion from ‘uint128_t’ to ‘long int’ is
ambiguous
uint128_t.h:83: note: candidates are: uint128_t::operator uint64_t()
uint128_t.h:79: note:                 uint128_t::operator uint32_t()
uint128_t.h:75: note:                 uint128_t::operator uint16_t()
uint128_t.h:71: note:                 uint128_t::operator uint8_t()
uint128_t.h:67: note:                 uint128_t::operator int()
uint128_t.h:63: note:                 uint128_t::operator char()
uint128_t.h:59: note:                 uint128_t::operator bool()
```

Comment: Please get your code viewer to include line numbers!

Comment: i dont think wikidot does that. and you didnt have to "goto line 593". you could just search for `operator<<`. its unlikely that there are too many of them in any code

Comment: Show the code for about 10 lines either side of line 593 - less if there are function boundaries.  Basically though, you need to work out how your I/O stream operator is going to print out 128-bit integers.  Converting to a shorter integer (such as `uint64_t`) might be part of the answer, but only if done carefully.

Comment: @calccrypto: I wasn't needing the line number to find the `operator<<` in error, I wanted to tell you what line needed to be replaced with the one in my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this variation:

```
out = "0123456789abcdef"[size_t(rhs % div)] + out;
```

since you've provided conversions to all manner of unsigned types, but not to signed int.

---

And yes, you can define an implicit conversion to `long int` just be defining `operator long` in the same manner as all the other conversions.

---

Finally, please note that your choice of structure name is reserved by POSIX, and likely to conflict with future versions of the standard library header `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. An int is an int is an int. It's a separate type from `long int`. As for which operators you overload, it depends entirely on *what you want to do*. You haven't really described that.

But if you want to define an operator to work on `int`, then you should overload it for `int`. If you want it to work on `long int`, define an overload for that.

What are you trying to do? And why are you passing a `uint128_t` to the operator, but asking about `int` and `long int`?

Comment: But you haven't posted the code that causes the error here (don't assume people are willing to 1) follow a link to an external site, and 2) read your entire program source code just to be able to help you. Post *the relevant* code here. You also haven't explained what the code is intended to *do*.